# What bracha to say first, cooked wheat (mezonos) or olives?

Tags: halacha, blessing, mezonot-beracha

According to this ordering

> "A land of wheat, barley, grapes, figs and pomegranates,
> a land of olives which produce oil, dates which produce honey." ([Deuteronomy 8:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.8.8?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0))

It is undecided as to whether to say the bracha rishona on wheat first or olives. Which one do we bless first?

Comment: https://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/17-Sequence-of-Brachot--Part-2.html

Comment: You could also ask on uncooked wheat (haadama) vs olives

Answer (score 4):

See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 211. The rule of following the order of the foods in the verse you cited essentially only applies when all the food items have the same blessing.

Otherwise, the order of priority for blessings is:

1. *hamotzi*
2. *mezonot*
3. *hagefen*
4. *ha'etz*/*ha'adamah*
5. *shehakol*

So in your case, recite *mezonot* on the cooked wheat product before *ha'etz* on the olives.